# Why Does My background Image Break My layout

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site with a transparent navbar with a background image with some text placed to it. When I tried to add a text under the background image but instead, the text moves to the top left of the page. how can l fix it?
here is the code:

```
.hero-image{
background-image: url('d.jpg'); 
height: 657px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

}
[This shows the background image with text at the top left. i want the text to be under the background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3ZXd.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't tell why some text isn't where you want it when you haven't shown it to us. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have used `position: absolute` for this; thats why your text moves to the top. Try to use following code may be it helps:

```css
.hero-image-outer{
  position: relative;
  height: 675px;
}
.hero-image{
background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/11635509/pexels-photo-11635509.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'); 
height: 100%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image-outer">
  <div class="hero-image"></div>    
  </div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Comment: It worked, Thanks as I would be using the top, left properties to align it

Comment: @Samuel Then please mark as correct answer.

Comment: I Have marked it as the correct answer